Pronumerals vs. variables in primary school maths instruction
I'm giving some supplemental mathematics tutoring for students in grades 5 to 7. Some of the text books do not distinguish between pronumerals and variables and use "variable" for both.
In my mind a variable, as the name suggests, changes. An equation should have both a independent variable (input) and dependent variable (output).
e.g. in y = 5x + 1 y and x are variables.
A pronumeral on the other hand would be a placeholder for an unknown that [ultimately] evaluates to a constant.
and in 7 = 5x + 1 x is a pronumeral (that evaluates to 7).
I don't think I'm being too pedantic, as there is only one value x can have in this case (it's not changing/variable).
Is this a useful distinction?

What you call a pronumeral, I'd rather call an unknown.

I've never heard of a pronumeral. It sounds confusing. At the middle school level, I wouldn't distinguish between an unknown and a variable. Also, equations don't have the notion of dependency. For example, which variable is the independent variable in the equation $x^2+y^2=1$? Inputs and outputs are more closely related to functions.

@JohnDouma, it is used in some areas to refer to symbols representing unknowns. But it is clearly not universal as I have looked at textbooks from around the world and only some use it.
You are right regarding the dependency not being strictly directional, I will keep that in mind, I was trying to get the idea across that variables change or represent a range of valid values (for instance in your example x and y could represent the coordinates of all the points on a unit circle centered on (0;0)).
Would your equation not be seen as an implicit function?

@GerryMyerson, I promise I did not make it up :). It's used in some parts of the world, primarily Australasia, and is intended to ease students into the idea of symbolic placeholders for numbers as a lead in to Algebra.

@AndreArtus An equation is a predicate whose value is either true or false depending upon the values of the variables. So $x^2+y^2=1$ is false for $(0,0)$ but true for $(1,0)$. The set of values for which the equation is true forms a unit circle centered at the origin. The Implicit Function theorem allows us to view either $x$ as a function of $y$ or $y$ as a function of $x$, depending upon which open set we take. Therefore, we cannot say which of $x$ or $y$ is independent in $x^2+y^2=1$ without further context.
